# Compute $\int{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+16}}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Here is what I have done so far:
$$I=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+16}} =\frac{1}{4}\int\sqrt{\frac{1}{\left(\frac{x}{4} \right)^2+1}}\,dx$$
$\frac{x}{4}=\tan(u), dx=4\sec^2(u)$
$$\therefore I=\int\sqrt{\frac{1}{\tan^2(u)+1}}\sec^2(u)\,du=\int\sec^3(u)\,du$$
now by integration by parts:
$$I=\tan(u)\sec(u)-\int\tan^2(u)\sec(u)\,du$$
I am sure $\int\sec^3(u)du$ is a standard integral but I am now sure if IBP is the best way to go. Is there another obvious way of doing it?

Comment: With [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint%7B%5Cfrac%7Bdx%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E2%2B16%7D%7D%7D%24&p=1) we can find many, many integrals of the form $\int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$. At least two with $a=4$ explicitly, $a=3$ and $a=2$ also appear there...

Comment: You've miscounted powers; you want to integrate the secant, not the cubed secant.

Comment: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/885238/11619) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1259731/11619)...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Substitute
$$\sqrt{x^2+16}=xt+4$$ this is the so-called Euler substitution.
See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution

Answer (score 0):

- Either you've learnt about   the *inverse hyperbolic functions*, and you know that
  $$\int\frac{\mathrm d x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\arg\sinh x=\ln\bigl(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\bigr),$$
  from which one deduces readily with the substitution  $x=at$ ($a>0$) that
  $$\int\frac{\mathrm d x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}=\arg\sinh \frac xa=\ln\bigl(x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\bigr).$$
- Or you've only learnt about the hyperbolic functions. In this case, set $x=a\sinh t$, $\mathrm d x=a\cosh t\,\mathrm d t$, so
  $$\int\frac{\mathrm d x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}=\int\frac{a\cosh t\,\mathrm d t}{a\sqrt{\sinh^2 t+1}}=\int\frac{\cosh t\,\mathrm d t}{\cosh t}=t.$$
  There remains to solve for $x$ the equation
  $$t=\sinh x=\frac{\mathrm e^{2x}-1}{2\mathrm e^x}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the trigonometric substitution as follows:

Let $$x = 4\times \tan(\theta)$$
By doing the necessary operations you will end up with $$\int \sec (\theta)\, d\theta $$
Which i guess you can easily solve